# Update custom page layout for managed package

Tags: managed-package

want to investigate if client will be able to updates to custom page layouts which are part of **managed package**?

Answer (score 0):

For Managed Package Page Layout, the following items are editable:

- Show Assignment Option
- Default Assignment Option
- Show Email Option
- Default Email Option
- Show Submit & Add Attachment Button

To simplify the upgrade process, all other attributes are locked. As the vendor might update the page layout in future.

Comment: Thanks Mehedi, is there any way we can allow client to make specific updates to custom page layouts which are part of the manage package.